# Number of points on elliptic curve $E:y^2 = x^3 +1$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q = p^n$ and $p\equiv 1 \mod 3$ for $p>3$

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves, zeta-functions

I am trying to find a general formula for the number of points on the elliptic curve $E:y^2 = x^3 +1$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q = p^n$ and $p\equiv 1 \mod 3$ for $p>3$. There should be enough literature on this which uses zeta functions etc. However, I can't seem to find a good reference on this. I also tried something myself: the endomorphism ring of $E$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$ and if we denote $\pi$ by the Frobenius endomorphism we know that $\pi\bar{\pi} = q$. Once we know how to write $\pi$ in this endomorphism ring we can calculate the number of points using some old results. Any idea how to continue/find references on this?

Comment: The curve is defined over $\Bbb{F}_p$. The Frobenius is $\phi_p(x,y)=(x^p,y^p)$. It commutes with the CM endomorphism $[\zeta_3](x,y)=(\omega_3 x,y)$ so $\phi_p= [a+b\zeta_3]$ with $|a+b\zeta_3|^2=p$.  There are 12 such elements in $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$, you'll find the two possible ones (up to complex conjugaison, but we only care of the trace of $\phi_p$) by looking at the action on $(0,1)+(\omega_3,0)$ a point of order $6$.

Comment: Maybe it’s worth reading up on modularity – the link between elliptic curves and modular forms. Anyway, see https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/36/a/4 .

Comment: Once you know $Tr(\phi_p)$ you can deduce $\#E(\Bbb{F}_{p^n})=p^n+1-Tr(\phi_p^n)$ for all $n$.

Comment: Once you figure out the case of prime fields you are done by Hasse-Davenport relations: the zeros of the $L$-function over the extension field are the appropriate powers of the zeros over the prime field - treat it via the trace of Frobenius if so desired!

Comment: @reuns that makes sense. Thank you! Is it possible to explicitely write down the 12 elements? And do we then have to compute the action $[a+b\zeta_3]$ on the point of order 6?

Comment: I meant $C=A+B=(0,1)+(-\omega_3,0)$ has order $6$. 
Then $[4]C=A$ and $[3]C = B$ so 
$\phi_p=[a+b\zeta_3]$ gives
$\phi_p C=[a+b\zeta_3]C = C$ so that
$[a+b]A=[a+b\zeta_3]A = A$ ie. $a+b\equiv 1\bmod 3$ and $[a+b\zeta_3]B = B$ ie. $b\equiv 0\bmod 2, a\equiv 1\bmod 2$.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! I figured it out :)